# Topics not visible on the community

Tags: community, visibility, topics

I am creating a community and I am setting communities topics.

Yesterday, I have a list of topics on the home page but today, they disappeared..

I think I don't have modified anything but I don't know what I have to set to display them.

Can you help me please?

More Topics can be visible by unlogged user?

Thanks
Aurélien

Comment: You should add more details like if its standard page and what settings you did.

Comment: I mean community home page.

Unfortunately, I think I didn't remove anything.

I checked on navigational topics and featured topics section, they still present.

A section or page to secify visibility of topics?

Comment: I just edited the home page to add the 'Featured topics' component on it and now, I can see topics but before, I didn't have this component displayed and I could see it.. why please?

Comment: Earlier were you displaying recently viewed topics by any chance?

Comment: I don't think so because they are same topics with the same order.

Very strange.